# Updating the data which do'nt have a DBHelper

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
 public void update(View v){String  amount1 = ct2.getText().toString(); //amount
    String barcode1 = ct1.getText().toString(); //barcode


    ct1.setText("");//barcode
    ct2.setText("");//amount

    db.execSQL("update mytable set amount = '"+amount1+"' wherebarcode='"+barcode1+"' "); 

    Toast.makeText(this, "values updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    this.finish();
}
```

*I'm creating app from android studio*

I try to update the data which already stored in '`mytable`' from `'mydb'`
I didn't use the **DBHelper** so that I couldn't see the exact table .
just instant code of SQLite .
I can insert new data but I couldn't `UPDATE` the data 
As my code it seem correctly .

while run the application everything pass with no error ,
I got the `barcode` value by scan with Mobile camera 
so in my table have
`NAME AMOUNT BARCODE` (in small)
the toast show that its updated successfully 
but When i go and check by
`SELECT * from mytable` 
the AMOUNT still the same as when i inserted

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Check out please your Query:

```
db.execSQL("update mytable set amount = '"+amount1+"' wherebarcode='"+barcode1+"' ");
```

You have no space after where clause. Edit and try again

Comment: The code is already have space (where barcode) but when i type here , i forget to recheck again and yeah thanx to let me see my point ^^ I’m still trying on code

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. The first is that there is no space between the WHERE keyword and  the column name. The second is, as you have found, that irrespective of the result of the UPDATE query that the TOAST will say that the UPDATE was successful.

To fix the first you would change

```
db.execSQL("update mytable set amount = '"+amount1+"' wherebarcode='"+barcode1+"' ");
```

to (i.e add the space):-

```
db.execSQL("update mytable set amount = '"+amount1+"' where barcode='"+barcode1+"' ");
```

However, as the `execSQL` method does not return a result, the second issue will remain. A fix is to use the `update` method, which will return the number of rows affected/updated.

As such you could use :-

```
    ContentValuse cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("amount",amount1); // Column to update and value to update the column to.
    if (db.update("mytable",cv,"barcode=?",new String[]{barcode1}) > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "values updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "not updated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

You may wish to look at :-

- [update](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)
- [ContentValues](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)

Comment: Wow that’s great let me try this, thanks for your answer ,and i will come back again. Whether it’s good or bad